# Xdebug is not enabled in PHP Version 7.1.21, XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug, netbeans-8

I have this configuration:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "G:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "G:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log = "G:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "G:\xampp\tmp"
;36000 = 10h
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

Please help. I am using Window 10.

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

I've had many difficulties in the past getting xdebug setup, but that little-known xdebug wizard has been a lifesaver for me in getting my xdebug settings right.

Comment: I have download the .dll file from https://xdebug.org/wizard.php but still have problem, it was working fine when was install php 5.6

Answer (score 0):

`Xdebug` and a `Xdebug Manager` are native with EasyPHP Deverser ([www.easyphp.org](http://www.easyphp.org)). Maybe you can have a look.